# Issue with browser adding '/' to end of url except index.php

Tags: php, html, macos, wordpress, firefox

I am currently doing web development on my macbook air. I am running the newest version of Firefox and for some reason I am having an issue with viewing it in Firefox with my mac-air. In Firefox the initial index.php URl loads fine without the proceeding `/` but any other pages automatically add a `/` to the end of the URL and I am unsure why. This causes problems because the pages CSS file then fails to load. I can manually remove the `/` but when I run the URL it is added back immediately.

- If I load the pages in Firefox on Ubuntu, everything is fine.
- If I load the pages in Chrome on OSX, everything is fine.

I am unsure of how to correct this issue. If a mod believes this is an osx, you can you move the post. I was going to post to Mac page but I'm assuming this is an issue with the browser or a known issue.
Be advised, I am just running these pages in a directory on my domain that has a wordpress site on it. The directory is separate from the wordpress files but still on the same godaddy server. The wordpress site is on the actual domain mydomain.com

- The development files I am trying to test are in mydomain.com/test/

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't an issue with your web-server configuration, maybe .htaccess file config is wrong...

Comment: You're running it locally? Can you paste in the URLs that you're attempting to access so we can see what you're browsing to? What happens when you attempt to browse to a .css file?

Comment: Fixed my issue by editing the .htaccess file. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this directory under the Wordpress root. If yes i'd look at your .htaccess it is probably doing something funky with the way routing/clean-urls is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some browsers think if there is no extension at the end of the URI, so it is a directory, so it appends '/' at the end (which is correct). To avoid it, you can force removal in htacces (if you are using Apache).